# rails cannot create a new item

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on creating a small rails app, and I have ran into a problem that I believe is in the backend of my database, but I don't know how to solve it.  Ultimately what is happening is if I try to go to my my `new` url, I get an error stating `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "caves" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"caves"'::regclass`

All I am trying to do us create a new `cafe` I go to `localhost:3000/cafes/new` but for some really annoying reason, caves somehow somewhere got in the mix and I don't know how to get around this.

My controller is essentially below. (the rest of the items in my controller are empty methods at this point)

```
  def new
    @cafe = Cafe.new
  end

  def create
    @cafe = Cafe.new(cafe_params)
  end

  private

  def cafe_params
    params.require(:name, :description)
  end
```

My schema table is

```
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "cafes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.integer "age"
  end
```

I have two empty models right now one called `user.rb` and the other `cafe.rb`

This is where I get really confused because there is no cave relation in my model.

```
class Cafe < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Thats about where I am. Would anyone know what I could do with this? I'm thinking that possibly there is a duplicate database somewhere and it needs to be destroyed. I've tried a `rake db:drop` + `rake db:create` + `rake db:migrate` route with what I have, but no luck.  I know there is a way to open up my database through straight up psql, and I think that may be the way into really truly debugging this problem.  (i've seen it done once, but don't remember how to do it, let alone only know active record, not sql)

Does anyone know whats going on here? Or does anyone know how to get into psql and how to find something like this?

I really do appreciate it.

Comment: error says relation "caves" and your model is "cafe", is there any spelling mistake?

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: I think there may have been something spelling related, but i with what I have, I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use inflections to solve this if you want plural of `cafe` to resolve to `cafes` instead of `caves` which rails does by default

To do so, add this to your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'cafe', 'cafes'
end
```

Comment: This ended up solving the issue and allowing me to continue.  I honestly don't understand exactly what active support inflectors are, but i'm happy that i was able to have it continue. Would you happen to know of some good documentation around the idea of inflections that I can take a look into?

Comment: rails' ActiveRecord resolves table names  like `leaves` to ActiveRecord model class `Leaf`, `caves` to ActiveRecord model class `Cafe` and vice versa (i.e tables with 'ves' are resolved to singular model class with 'f') by default .. So if you want otherwise, then those assumed translations can be changed as inflectors .. When you configure the preferred translation as above in `config/initializers/inflections.rb` This means `cafe` is single  entry on table `cafes` NOT `caves` .. You can read more about it here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html .. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Have you run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`?

Because the table name build with model name `Cafe` is `caves`.

So try run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`. and restart rails sever will solve your problem.

```
pry(main)> 'Cafe'.tableize
=> "caves"
```

Comment: Hey bud, thanks for taking a look. That was one of the first things that I did try, and it didn't quite solve the issue.  I think there was somehow as I was putting things together the whole `caves` came into the mix, and it regardless of what I did with the database, it was still lingering in there.

Answer (score 0):

```html
def new
    @cafe = Cafe.new
  end

  def create
    @cafe = Cafe.new(cafe_params)
    @cafe.save
  end

  private

  def cafe_params
    params.require[:modelname].permit(:name, :description)
  end
```

Try This Code